# Java - can I save HttpServletResponse res.getWriter()

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to save this writer in the servlet, so that it is always available for me, not only in the doPost method (where I get the HttpServletResponse), but my approach doesn't seem to work. When I writer something in the saved PrintWriter it just never seems to reach the client. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please paste the problematic piece of code? What do you mean by save? Assigning it to a variable?

Comment: Yes, assign it to a field inside the servlet and use it when needed.